# UIButton of UIButtonTypeCustom with title does not show as clicked

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am setting up the following UIButton (in tableview cell) for the intention of making it look like an URL link that's clickable

```
UIButton *buttonUserName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonUserName.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 20);
[buttonUserName setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonUserName setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonUserName setEnabled:YES];
buttonUserName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[buttonUserName addTarget:self action:@selector(user:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:buttonUserName];
```

The button and title does show up, but it has not click effect (visually) when I tap it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: have u implemented `@selector(user:)` whats there ?

Comment: I did, but it's essentially noop. - (IBAction)user:(id)sender { }

Comment: you get solution or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the the visually feedbacks you want to the button state `UIControlStateHighlighted`

for example: title color

```
[buttonUserName setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

and some else title, background image, image etc.

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```
 [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:buttonUserName];
```

i suppose that you overlap any another view to button

Answer (score 0):

Try to put some `UIAlert` or `NSLog` there to see if you are getting the tap event. since after the user taps your button the event goes to `(IBAction)user:(id)sender`

Comment: Actually, it did go there to the method, I debugged it. I guess I need to phrase the question more clearly - "the button was not visually showing as clicked, how to do that programmingly?"

Comment: "not visually showing as clicked" what do you mean by this? what do you expect once someone taps on the button ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question:

1. It has no click effect: This is because you have used a UIButtonTypeCustom. If you want to use  a custom button, you should give an image for that button. Or else you should use UIButtonTypeRoundedRect, and you will get that click effect.
2. As Srikar pointed out, put some alert in the user: method, and you can see that code being executed.

Hope that helps!